# Change app name depending on localization

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I am using Corona SDK.

How do I programmatically change the application name on the home screen if the locale is in

Sample App Name: "Super Ball"

English: "Super Ball"
Japanese: "スーパーボール"
Chinese: "超级球"

Comment: Why would you want to do that 'programmatically' when the Android framework has it all built in? Just set up your `strings.xml` files and put them in the relevant resource folders; i.e. `res/values-en`, `res/values-jp`, `res/values-cn` etc. Then chuck in `android:label="@string/app_name"` and you're good to go.

Comment: I'm using Corona SDK, how can I do it?

Comment: There is no way to do it in Corona PRO. It is possible in Corona Enterprise. For more info see http://www.coronalabs.com/store/

Answer (score 1):

it's old but in case someone else arrived here like me.

In fact it seems there is a possibility to do it with [Corona Pro.](http://lauratallardy.com/app-localization-made-easy/)

At the end of the page you have a solution for iOS.

And on the [corona forum approach](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/38972-does-corona-support-app-name-localization/) for both.

Answer (score 0):

@vovahost is right: not possible without corona enterprise.

Altough you can do a workaoround. You could locate the user and get the country out of it. Or just give the option to select a language at start.